# Does zipkin support activemq as a collector?

Tags: activemq-classic, zipkin

I want to use ActiveMQ as a zipkin collector. I have already used rabbitmq as collector, but my client is specific to using ActiveMQ. Please let know if Zipkin supports ActiveMQ as collector and what are the configurations needed for that?